# Windows 8 Emulator stuck at "The windows phone is starting"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am trying to develop a Windows phone app, but the emulator is kinda acting weird. I hit the F5 key, or click Emulator WVGA 512MB (or anything in the list), it bring up the emulator. It say "Loading..." and then goes to the "The windows phone is starting" screen and stalls.

Coreinfo -v yields

```
Coreinfo v3.2 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2012 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Note: Coreinfo must be executed on a system without a hypervisor running for
accurate results.

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 0 @ 3.20GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             -       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
```

Everything looks good, but I don't know what's going on. I am on Windows 8, VS Ultimate 2012.

It is the first time it is doing this.

At BIOS level too, I have enabled/disabled as mentioned in the article:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj863509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx
```

Your help is immensely appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19):

I landed here after experiencing the same problem. However, after 5 to 10 minutes the emulator eventually loaded the phone.

Firing up the emulator thereafter was pretty quick.

So if you've landed here with the same problem, and it's the first time Visual Studio has tried to run the emulator be sure to give it enough time.

Comment: It seems patience is indeed key: giving it a good few minutes resulted in it loading up just fine. I found that each emulator type/mode required its own chuck of initial load time, but subsequent loads of the same type/mode were far quicker.

Answer (score 0):

It is now working. thanks for looking and now helping out! uninstallation/installation worked, with a lot of other issues in between.

Comment: Please, consider sharing your step-by-step solution.