# Windows Phone 8.1 emulator stuck at starting OS

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I did fresh W10 and VS 2015 install and now when i try running newly created hello world type of app on emulator it doesn't load, all it says is:
[image: Emulator text]
 after 5-10 minutes it exits and Visual studio returns DEP6100 (error on bootstrapping stage - connecting to device) and DEP6200 (Device not found) errors.

However VM itself starts, boots up and works in Hyper-V

[image: VM works]

Things i tried:

- Change/Repair Windows 8.1 emulator (nothing changed)
- Change/Repair Visual studio (nothing changed)
- Re-install Visual studio (nothing changed)
- Change Switch type in Hyper V from internal to private (When emulator windows popped it it prompted that there is error with resolving host ip, but booted up and actually this time passed Windows Phone OS is starting screen and actually booted up, but Visual Studio somehow didn't recognize that and after a few minutes of it booting up it forcefully shut down VM and returned same error codes)
- Removing all ethernet adapters (including my computer one) and then checking for hardware changes so it would create them again. (They were recreated but didn't help, there are only 3 adapters now (Ethernet, Wifi and vEthernet(Windows phone internal Switch)
- Relaunching it billion of times without changing anything (somehow didn't work)

Comment: Related question with an answer that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230855/windows-phone-emulator-8-1-10-stuck-at-loading-the-os

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, after around 2 days of non-stop googling i found a solution from other stackoverflow question where someone had similar problem but with Android emulator 
[Visual studio (2015) emulator for android not working - XDE.exe - Exit Code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31613607/visual-studio-2015-emulator-for-android-not-working-xde-exe-exit-code-3)

What I did was:

1. Delete All VMs in Hyper V
2. Delete All switches in Hyper V
3. Run xdecleanup.exe for every version of XDE (Found at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft XDE/ [8.0/8.1/10.0.10240.0] /XdeCleanup.exe
4. Run Change/Repair on 'Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators - ENU'
5. Restart Visual Studio

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem after a fresh install and this actually fixed it.

Answer (score 11):

I tried what you did and it didn't work. So I did the following:

1. Go to "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections"
2. right click on "vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)".
3. Choose properties and check the case "Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch" and click OK.
4. Again right click on vEthernet and disable it. Then re-enable it.
5. Run the VM and wait for a few minutes (The 1st time is always longer to load)

Comment: This worked for me - however, only ONE of my emulators is working (8.1 WVGA 4.5 inch 512 MB) and the rest of them are stuck at loading OS.

Comment: Worked for me. There was a confusion though: the switch did not stay checked, there was a warning after clicking OK: "Your current selection will also disable the following features: Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch, Are you sure?". But still, the emulator started working then.

Comment: For anyone else it might help, in my case, Symantec Endpoint Protection firewalled the connection.

Comment: @JosephKatzman My solution is the accepted answer on this page.

Comment: @JosephKatzman Sorry, I wasn't reading carefully. If I recall, I followed this (DomDev's) answer, but it didn't work until I disabled Symantec. If that helps you, you'll need to configure Symantec's firewall to let HyperV and/or the vEthernet port through. Sorry, I don't know how (this was a long time ago).

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for Visual Studio on Windows 10.  Allow the following app through your firewall.  If you don't have a firewall installed then you are using the built in Windows version:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\XDE.exe"

Note that the actual path may change depending which emulator you have installed.

Comment: I've done this but didn't help.. I've added this program in to my Windows default firewall but still OS not starting.. any further help please..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the Windows 10 Mobile emulators which suddenly stopped working after disabling and re-enabling the Hyper V features of Windows 10 once.

What fixed it for me was this:

1. Open **Control Panel** -> **Network and Internet** -> **Network Connections**

There should be an adapter named **vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)**. (Actually I had 2 of those, one showing a red cross saying "Network cable unplugged" and one saying "Unidentified network" - I chose the latter for the following steps).

2. Right-click the adapter and choose **Properties**
3. Switch to tab **Sharing**
4. Check the **first option** "Allow other network users to connect...", uncheck the second option "Allow other users to control or disable..."
5. As **home network connection** choose **vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)**
6. Switch back to the first tab **Networking**
7. Uncheck the item **Internet Protocol Version 6**
8. Click **OK** and also click **OK** in the message dialog that follows (saying something about IP addresses)

Visual Studio 2015 was open the whole time while doing this. After these steps I pressed F5, waited some time (1-2 minutes) for the OS to boot and the app started.

(This solution is similar to the one proposed over in the MS [forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1734dac7-37a4-4d9a-bf89-42b6d493adda/windows-phone-emulator-internal-switch-no-ip-adresss?forum=wptools&prof=required).)

Note: the solution provided by DomDev did not work for me. I did not try the one by Edgar.A

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, and stupid, but my problem was that there wasn't enough disk space on my machine!

Answer (score -1):

The following comment, from [a reply on the Xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/217754/#Comment_217754)
works:

> make sure the compatibility setting is checked under processor for all the emulators you use